# Can the following jq recipe be simplified

Tags: json, jq

Using jq version 1.5, I need to conditionally output some json objects (in an array) based on a value within the nested object.  I've looked here on StackOverflow and managed to get what I want working, but I wonder if it can be simplified.  Here's my data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Rich",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "age": 11
    },
    {
      "name": "Victoria",
      "age": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "Philip",
      "age": 9
    }
  ]
}
```

and I need to reproduce the same structure, but only for pupils 10 or older, so the output should look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Rich",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "age": 11
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the following code which achieves what I want:

```
.data | to_entries | map(select(.value.age>9)) | [.[].value] | {data: .}
```

but I read in the jq manual that `with_entries` can be used to replace `to_entries` -> `map` -> `from_entries`, now I'm not using `from_entries`, but it made me question whether I should be, and if it would mean I don't need to manually recreate my array and object in the last two pipes.

Is this the best way to solve this type of problem?

I tried using using `from_entries` after my map, to see if that did what I need, but I got an error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:19): Cannot use number (0) as object key
```

So my understanding of how that works isn't correct.

Comment: version 1.5 is quite old now, consider upgrading to v1.7

Answer (score 4):

```
.data |= map(select(.age >= 10))
```

Will produce the same output in a more cleaner way as you can test in [this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IsFLD8c8sH2).

---

Using the [`|=` update assignment](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#update-assignment) to update the value of `.data`.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an array, so you don't need to convert to entries first. Simply `map` the array and `select` the required elements:

```
.data |= map(select(.age >= 10))
```

Alternatively

```
.data | { data: map(select(.age >= 10)) }
```

or

```
{ data: (.data | map(select(.age >= 10))) }
```

Calling `to_entries` on an array will give you a new array with a key-value object, the key being the index:

```
[
  {
    "key": 0,
    "value": {
      "name": "Rich",
      "age": 10
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

So unless your condition needs to perform calculations on the index (say, selecting every 3rd element, or only those indices which are multiples of 5), you don't need `to_entries` here.